# Why is the backpropagation of 2D convolution failing with Tensorflow when using a distribute strategy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing, backpropagation

I followed the tutorial of Tensorflow to enable multi GPU training (from a single computer) with a distribute strategy for my custom training loop: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training?hl=en#use_tfdistributestrategy_with_custom_training_loops

I tried using the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` as well as the `tf.distribute.experimental.CentralStorageStrategy` but both give me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 468, in <module>
    app.run(run_main)
  File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 462, in run_main
    main(**kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 424, in main
    trainer.training_loop(train_dataset, test_datasets, distribute_strategy=strategy)
  File "train.py", line 271, in training_loop
    distribute_strategy.run(self.run_train_step, args=(X, y, y_prev, write_image_examples))
  File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 1312, in run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 2888, in call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py", line 3689, in _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/SINet/si_net/s2_module_5/conv2d_16/grouped_0/conv2d_35/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "train.py", line 468, in <module>
      app.run(run_main)
    File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
      _run_main(main, args)
    File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in _run_main
      sys.exit(main(argv))
    File "train.py", line 462, in run_main
      main(**kwargs)
    File "train.py", line 424, in main
      trainer.training_loop(train_dataset, test_datasets, distribute_strategy=strategy)
    File "train.py", line 271, in training_loop
      distribute_strategy.run(self.run_train_step, args=(X, y, y_prev, write_image_examples))
    File "train.py", line 172, in run_train_step
      gradients = tape.gradient(overall_loss, self.model.trainable_weights)
Node: 'gradient_tape/SINet/si_net/s2_module_5/conv2d_16/grouped_0/conv2d_35/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput'
Detected at node 'gradient_tape/SINet/si_net/s2_module_5/conv2d_16/grouped_0/conv2d_35/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "train.py", line 468, in <module>
      app.run(run_main)
    File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
      _run_main(main, args)
    File "/home/rroyerrivard/repos/research_sinet/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in _run_main
      sys.exit(main(argv))
    File "train.py", line 462, in run_main
      main(**kwargs)
    File "train.py", line 424, in main
      trainer.training_loop(train_dataset, test_datasets, distribute_strategy=strategy)
    File "train.py", line 271, in training_loop
      distribute_strategy.run(self.run_train_step, args=(X, y, y_prev, write_image_examples))
    File "train.py", line 172, in run_train_step
      gradients = tape.gradient(overall_loss, self.model.trainable_weights)
Node: 'gradient_tape/SINet/si_net/s2_module_5/conv2d_16/grouped_0/conv2d_35/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: Size of out_backprop doesn't match computed: actual = 32, computed = 96 spatial_dim: 3 input: 96 filter: 1 output: 32 stride: 1 dilation: 1
     [[{{node gradient_tape/SINet/si_net/s2_module_5/conv2d_16/grouped_0/conv2d_35/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput}}]]
     [[cond/then/_117/cond/train/image/write_summary/ReadVariableOp/_162]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: Size of out_backprop doesn't match computed: actual = 32, computed = 96 spatial_dim: 3 input: 96 filter: 1 output: 32 stride: 1 dilation: 1
     [[{{node gradient_tape/SINet/si_net/s2_module_5/conv2d_16/grouped_0/conv2d_35/Conv2D/Conv2DBackpropInput}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_run_train_step_59237]
```

That is with Tensorflow 2.8, but I also tried 2.9 and got the same error. The training goes perfectly well when I'm not using a distribute strategy. What could cause the issue? The dataset is the same (apart from being distributed by the strategy just like the tutorial is instructing) and the model structure doesn't change, so that shape error makes absolutely no sense to me.

Here is some of my code, in case this helps.

```py
def main(...):
    physical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    num_gpu = len(physical_gpus)
    for gpu in physical_gpus:
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

    if num_gpu > 1:
        strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
        # strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.CentralStorageStrategy()
    else:
        strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()
    tf.get_logger().info('Distribute strategy: {}'.format(strategy))

    with strategy.scope():
        dataset_loader = DatasetLoader(...)

        train_dataset, test_datasets = dataset_loader.prepare(
            datasets_path=datasets_path, distribute_strategy=strategy)

        model = Model(...)
        trainer = Train(...)
        trainer.training_loop(train_dataset, test_datasets, distribute_strategy=strategy)

class Train(object):
    [...]

    def training_loop(self, training_dataset: tf.data.Dataset, testing_datasets: Dict, distribute_strategy: tf.distribute.Strategy):

        for epoch in tf.range(self.epoch, self.num_epochs):
            for batch_num, (X, y, y_prev) in enumerate(training_dataset):
                tf.get_logger().info(f'starting batch inference')
                start = time.time()
                distribute_strategy.run(self.run_train_step, args=(X, y, y_prev))
                tf.get_logger().info(f'batch inference took {time.time() - start}s')

    @tf.function
    def run_train_step(self, image_channels, label, previous_label):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            mask = self.model(image_channels, training=True)
            pred_loss = self.compute_loss(label, mask)

        gradients = tape.gradient(pred_loss, self.model.trainable_weights)  # CRASHES HERE!!!!!!!!
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_weights))

class DatasetLoader(object):
    [...]
    
    def prepare(self, datasets_path="./data", skip_train=False, shuffle=True, distribute_strategy=None):
        options = tf.data.Options()
        options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = tf.data.experimental.AutoShardPolicy.DATA
        
        train_dataset = None if skip_train else self._load_dataset(datasets_path, "trainA", "trainB", options, training=True, shuffle=shuffle)
        portrait_test_dataset = self._load_dataset(datasets_path, "testPortraitA", "testPortraitB", options, training=False, shuffle=shuffle)
        video_test_dataset = self._load_dataset(datasets_path, "testVideoA", "testVideoB", options, training=False, shuffle=shuffle)
        test_datasets_dict = {"portrait": portrait_test_dataset, "video": video_test_dataset}

        if distribute_strategy is not None:
            train_dataset = distribute_strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(train_dataset)
            for key in test_datasets_dict:
                test_datasets_dict[key] = distribute_strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(test_datasets_dict[key])

        return train_dataset, test_datasets_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing the code at the end of my post, I tried some minor changes I haven't thought about before and randomly found the culprit. The `@tf.function` decorator above the `run_train_step` function was causing the issue! I think I added it by mistake while implementing the distribute strategy changes. After I removed it, I was able to successfully run the training. However, Tensorflow prints this kind of warning for both strategies...

> WARNING:tensorflow:Using CentralStorageStrategy eagerly has
> significant overhead currently. We will be working on improving this
> in the future, but for now please wrap `call_for_each_replica` or
> `experimental_run` or `run` inside a tf.function to get the best
> performance.